Swiftui Image - Magnify and Drag simultaneously with two touches
Setting simultaneous gestures with MagnificationGesture and DragGesture do not work together since drag gesture works on single touch and magnification works on two touch. I am either able to magnify with two touches or drag with one touch with below approach.
Image(uiImage: "image_file_name")
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFit()
    .scaleEffect(zoomFactor)
    .offset(offset)
    .gesture(
        MagnificationGesture()
            .updating($zoomFactor) { value, scale, transaction in
                scale = value > 1 ? value : 1
            }
            .simultaneously(with:  DragGesture()
                .onChanged { val in
                    offset = val.translation
                }
            )
    )

What I want is enabling user the simultaneously drag and magnify with two touches an Image.
As far as I understand custom gestures are not an available option, and since drag gesture works with one touch, how to achieve it?

This answer might help: How to implement three gestures at the same time in Swift?

Great solution but not useful for my case. @BenzyNeez
